# CSS - Scroll behaviour smooth not working on pageload

Tags: css

When I click an anchor link that is linking to an ID on the same page, it's working. However, it's not working when I click a link on another page that is linking to a certain page and a certain anchor. Do I need JavaScript for this expected behavior?

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: try looking into [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)